# js news api promise not able to fetch certain values

Tags: javascript

I have a js function that get the top news headlines. It's returned in a promise, but I'm having trouble accessing the articles. Here is my code

```js
function news09() {
      var url = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?' +
        'country=us&' +
        'apiKey=KEY';
      var req = new Request(url);
      console.log(req)
      fetch(req)
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(({articles}) => console.log(articles))
        .then(console.log(["0"].author));
```

But the problem is that the last line of the code,`.then(console.log(["0"].author));` , doesn't log the author's name, but just shows up as undefined. What I want to do, is to get the data in `articles`, and use it elsewhere. Any help appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What in the world are you expecting that statement to do? Arrays don't have an `author` property, as you hopefully are aware. In addition, you're invoking a function rather than passing a function reference to `.then()`, which will cause it to execute immediately, as you probably did not intend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two issues.

First, you have to give a function to a promise `.then` method. So the line:

```
.then(console.log(["0"].author));
```

will execute the `console.log` immediately, and since you're logging the property `author` of an array (which has no such property), you'll always get `undefined`.

Second, the line:

```
.then(({articles}) => console.log(articles))
```

will log the articles property of the object you get from your fetch, *but* returns undefined since you don't forward the `articles` value, you only log it. So any `.then` functions after that point are going to receive `undefined` as their argument.

You might modify your code like so to fix those issues:

```
function news09() {
  var url = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?' +
    'country=us&' +
    'apiKey=13f8c711183c43c1b74dd5912de8310a';
  var req = new Request(url);
  console.log(req)
  fetch(req)
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    // Make sure to return articles from this function after logging it
    .then(({articles}) => { console.log(articles); return articles; })
    // Take the articles as an argument, then log the author property of the first entry.
    .then(articles => console.log(articles["0"].author));
```